# Display 1 product per row on mobile view in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I've set the mobile product page to 1 row. So all the products are underneath eachother.

How ever this is not the case. I still see 2 rows in responsive mobile view:

https://fermultimedia.com/shop/

I'm using woocommerce astra and elementor pro

Help is appriciated. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS will solve your issue:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    
.elementor-element.elementor-products-grid ul.products{ 
    display:inline !important; 
}
    
.elementor-element .elementor-wc-products .woocommerce[class*=columns-] ul.products li.product { 
margin: 20px !important;
}
    
}
```

Comment: I did work thank you! Even tho the question is closed and disliked by 3 people. You answer did exactly what I wanted. Thanks again.